# Background image and color not showing up on IE

Tags: css

Background under Slider and Footer in all browsers is fine, except IE - http://wp.color-theme.com/webster/

Any ideas?

Comment: Not a Wordpress related question.

Comment: This is a CSS question, not a wordpress question. Webmasters.stackexchange is where you need to be for that.

Comment: From the faq: Please note that if your question is about detailed HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding, it might be a better fit on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a separate background-color and transparent background-image. Create a new background image that has the background color baked in. This will make it display correctly in IE.